# How to add a titledpane to an Accordion by click a button?

Tags: javafx, pane

I'm building a program with JavaFX and I have an Accordion `ac` injected `@FXML` and I have a button that creates a titled pane in the Accordion. The problem is that this button on click adds a titled pane to the accordion once.

I'm using this code:

```
t1.setContent(l);
ac.getPanes().add(t1);
```

I want to add one pane every click on this button. Please help me and thank you!

Comment: Where have you created the TitledPane `t1`? Can you add the code for the complete `onAction()` of the button?

Answer (score 2):

is this what you are looking for?

**Scene.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="404.0" prefWidth="543.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="pl.brocode.tg.magisterka.mavenproject1.FXMLController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="193.0" layoutY="283.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="193.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="193.0" />
      <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" prefViewportHeight="160.0" prefViewportWidth="320.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <content>
            <Accordion fx:id="accordion" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**FXMLController**

```
package test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

     @FXML
    private Accordion accordion;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        AnchorPane newPanelContent = new AnchorPane();
        newPanelContent.getChildren().add(new Label("Hello World"));
        TitledPane pane = new TitledPane("World Pane", newPanelContent);
        System.out.println(accordion);
        accordion.getPanes().add(pane);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

every time you click a button, new panel is added. if you wane do something with that panel in the future, you can assign it to field (list), or get it from accordion via `getChildren()` method.

an edit has been made to a code, for better display of added panes